How do I undo the most recent actions in power bi?
I encountered an issue in Power BI after importing data from SQL Server, which included both dimension and fact tables. after  adding some visualizations i tried to go back to data transformation process to sort the year column in the dimension table ,but after i applied the changes and closed the trasformation process, the calculations for the total NASales, EUSales, and JPSales decimals became incorrect. Previously, everything was functioning correctly.
Despite attempting to revert the sorting, closing and reopening Power BI, and even reinstalling the application and re-importing the data from SQL Server, the calculations remain inaccurate compared to their initial state. https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232685282747351111/1232698150469374074/image.png?ex=662a671d&is=6629159d&hm=dcd3a351494728eaf7a36c58b52d00f56fe572fe134644360351f3e859e61fcd&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1440&height=370   picture number 2 https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232685282747351111/1232698150955782224/image.png?ex=662a671d&is=6629159d&hm=7275a67d61476dd0ec62151b05400c8e9c102e5aca18edd2ce66a9203858ae84&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1069&height=578 and picture number three  https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1232685282747351111/1232698151308234833/image.png?ex=662a671d&is=6629159d&hm=dbee77fc934ebd3804e4d75658a9c13240f52d3f04861bbc82bb8e441c0d0cfc&=&format=webp&quality=lossless&width=1134&height=578

Please do not link to outside link in your question
